# Exporting flash cs6 to flash player 11.8

Tags: flash, export, publishing

When we press ctrl + enter to export flash movie, I want it to export it to latest flash player installed in my computer. But in publishing options of flash cs6, 11.8 version is not available. The latest option is 11.4.

The reason I want to do that is because 11.4 does not support right mouse up event. And m tracing values during runtime, simply opening the swf in 11.8 won't help my job. Dats y I want the software to export to 11.8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some instructions that work for updating Flash CS6 to use any new version of Flash Player (including 11.8):

http://johnbarrett.net/updating-flash-professional-cs6-to-support-11-5/

The instructions are for Mac OSX but work on Windows as well.