# How do I get larger-than-2048-pixel textures working in Stage3D?

Tags: actionscript-3, textures, flash, stage3d

About half way down this page...
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplatform/whitepapers/roadmap.html
...under the heading 'Flash Player 11.8 and AIR 3.8' it says there is support for 4096 x 4096 textures and support for rectangular textures. Given that '2048' and 'square' were the restrictions for Stage3D textures I'm assuming this new support refers to Stage3D.

I have followed the instructions on this page...
[Exporting flash cs6 to flash player 11.8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17859539/exporting-flash-cs6-to-flash-player-11-8)
...(made a copy of the FlashPlayer11_4.xml file, altered it and resaved it as FlashPlayer11_8.xml, downloaded the 11.8 playerglobal.swc and switched to targeting 11.8) but when I try to include a 4096 x 2048 texture it still throws an error, saying the maximum size is 2048. Is there something I'm missing?

I'm using Flash CS6.

Comment: If you will find an answer , please post it here

Comment: Check if `FlashPlayer11_4.xml` actually contains the 2048x2048 restriction somewhere, probably to ease the texture requirements you need to alter the XML.

Comment: I have checked again and there is no reference to texture size in the .xml file.

Answer (score 0):

The feature can only be supported if the Graphic card or the Graphic card drivers can support it, it is not just a matter of having and targeting the right FP version.